# Archive folders only when the folder has certain file types

Tags: powershell

How to write PowerShell script to archive folders only when the folder has files of certain type for instance `.txt`, `.csv`, `.xls`, `.xlsx`. My source path is `C:\Temp\Test\` and there are 5 sub-folders:

- foldera
- folderb
- folderc
- folderd
- foldere
- Archive

Only `foldera`, `folderb`, `folderc` have the files to be archived, the archive path is `C:\Temp\Test\Archive` and this has `folders` `foldera`, `folderb` so these folders need not be created but files need to be zipped and copied, `folderc` needs to be created and the files have to be zipped and copied.

Using the code below I get the files but not the folder that particular file was in.

```
    $ignorefolders = @(
    "C:\Temp\misc"   
    )

$archive = "C:\Temp\Archive" 

[regex]$exclude = ‘(?i)^(‘ + (($ignorefolders |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)’

$includefiletype = @("*.txt", "*.csv", "*.dat", "*.xls", "*.xlsx")     
$workingDir = "C:\Temp"

Get-ChildItem $workingDir -recurse -include $fileFilter | Where {$_.FullName -notmatch $exclude} | Copy-Item -Destination $archive
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the directories, select the Directory property of the `FileInfo` objects returned from `Get-ChildItem`, I'm also assuming that you don't want any duplicates, so, you'll have to filter those out using `sort`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $source -include*.txt,*.csv,*.xls,*.xlsx | select directory | sort -Unique -Property Directory | Select -expand Directory | Copy-Item -Destination $archive -WhatIf
```

Comment: I get "Copy-Item Cannot find drive" error, shouldn't Copy-Item have the source path specified. When I change Copy-Item to "Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $archive -WhatIf" I get parameter binding error.

Comment: It seems like Copy-Item doesn;t like the FileInfo object as input, so  made an edit to expand the property before it's sent to Copy-Item, However, I have a feeling that still not going to do what you want. You probably want to add a -Recurse argument to Copy-Item.

Comment: I am able to filter files and folders using the below script. But, it copies just the folders and all the files get copied outside. How do I copy the folders with the files.

Comment: Updated the original post with the modified powershell script.